# @Secured service methods and spring ws

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ws

I have the following project structure:

base project (service layer, model)
  web project
  webservice project

where both the web project and the web service project depend on the base project and use services provided by it.

I make heavy use of the Spring Framework which means the Services are Spring Beans with methods secured by the **@Secured** Annotation and **Spring Security**. I created an **Voter** extending the AbstractAclVoter that checks client permissions.

The web project uses **Spring MVC** and the web service project **Spring WS** with @Endpoint Annotations and the **XwsSecurityInterceptor**.

Here is my problem:

The permissions are checked if a call comes from a web project controller or in JUnit tests of the base project but requests from the web service project are not checked for the correct permission - my **Voter** is not called!

- Has this something to do with the **XwsSecurityInterceptor**?
- Do I need the **DelegatingFilterProxy** in the web service project too? (I have
  no ContextLoaderListener there because everything is configured by
  the MessageDispatcherServlet config)

Comment: I think some code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user authentication object with populated Granted Authority is available only in the web context not in your web services project. When you make a call to your web service application, you don't have the same security context over there. So your security tags won't work over there.

Comment: but this would mean that I need to do Basic Authentication for my SOAP requests instead of using XwsSecurityInterceptor and the security headers in the SOAP request?

Comment: See also my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294517/propagate-spring-security-from-webapp-to-soap-webservice/10295617#10295617

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security integrates as a servlet filter in the web application. So I would assume that the DelegatingFilterProxy will need to be added to web.xml for the web services project so that it can process the requests going to that application.