# propagate spring security from webapp to soap webservice

Tags: spring, soap, spring-security, spring-ws, ws-security

I have the following situation: we have several webapplications, all using Spring Security to do authentication/authorization. We want to create a webservice that will be used by all those webapplications. Communication will hapen over https.

I want the security context of the webapp to propagate to the webservice, so that @Secured annotations on methods in the webservice implementation work correctly.
I've looked at [spring ws security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/security.html), and have succesfully implemented authentication using the UsernameTokenProfile. But I can't seem to find a standards-based way to transfer the authorization info (ie the roles of the user).

1. is there a way in Spring to do authorization in webservices? (SAML,XACML?)
2. does Spring even build a SecurityContext when using authentication in webservices? If I debug my code and ask for SecurityContextHolder.getContext() I get null (I'm assuming my request is handled by 1 thread).

Answer (score 1):

As Apache CXF is configured through Spring-based configuration file, I would suggest you take a look at its documentation regarding [AUTHORIZATION](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html)

I think that might help you

Comment: I'm not sure what CXF authorization adds, documentation is rather sparse it seems. But it looks like I would still have to retrieve the roles for a given user, where I would like to transport the roles in the webservice call, and reuse existing code with Spring Security annotations on the serverside. I could rolly my own solution easily but I wandered if there is standard way for transfering a security context.